# Exportar texto tabulado no Excel

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, phpexcel

Olá

Preciso gerar um arquivo de texto baseado nesse layout para que seja importado em um sistema. Estou tentando usar o Excel, crio as células com os devidos tamanhos conforme pede o layout.

No Excel vou em "salvar como" e escolho: "Texto formatado (separado por espaço) prn" fica quase tudo certo, porém na a partir da linha 27 ele desconfigura, vai dá uma quebra de linha. Precisaria que ficasse o arquivo final ficasse igual ao do Excel porém em txt e obedecendo as tabulações.

Tentei salvar com todas as outras opções do Excel porém não obedece as tabulações no arquivo final.

Alguém pode me ajudar? É possível fazer isso pelo Excel? Pelo que entendi é uma limitação do .prn

layoyt:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída com erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia! Não é uma limitação do _.prn_, teste aqui com 1000 linhas e funcionou perfeitamente. A separação por espaço, ao salvar o Excel segue o tamanho definido na coluna, utilize o notepad++ pra abrir o seu arquivo _.prn_ e faça testes.

Comment: Bom Dia!

Na verdade me referi a limitação das colunas e não linhas, de fato as linhas não tem limite.

Você conseguiu gerar um arquivo .prn a partir do Excel com as 33 colunas e todas obedecendo os espaçamentos? Faço isso e abro no notepad++ e na coluna 27 ele quebra a linha. Obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: Verdade para coluna tem limitação de 240... fiz uma adaptação no código abaixo mas deve funcionar com a planilha ativa!

Comment: No exemplo da Microsoft, para sanar essa limitação, eles colocam apenas as células selecionadas, fiz uma pequena adaptação para exportar a planilha ativa, mas pode fazer conforme achar melhor ai. Se tiver dificuldade com o código fico à disposição amigo. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

De fato existe uma limitação no Excel até 240 para colunas, mas a própria Microsoft nos dá uma luz.

Segue abaixo modelo adaptado da Microsoft para exporta todos os dados da planilha ativa para um arquivo texto:

```
Sub ExportText()

Dim delimiter As String
Dim quotes As Integer
Dim Returned As String

   delimiter = " "

   quotes = MsgBox("Coloca informações das células com aspas?", vbYesNo)

   ' Chama a função WriteFile
   Returned = WriteFile(delimiter, quotes)

   ' Mensagem Final
   Select Case Returned
      Case "Canceled"
          MsgBox "A operação foi cancelada"
      Case "Exported"
         MsgBox "O arquivo foi exportado com sucesso!"
   End Select

End Sub


Function WriteFile(delimiter As String, quotes As Integer) As String

Dim CurFile As String
Dim SaveFileName
Dim CellText As String
Dim RowNum As Integer
Dim ColNum As Integer
Dim FNum As Integer
Dim TotalRows As Double
Dim TotalCols As Double

' Indica local e arquivo a ser exportado
If Left(Application.OperatingSystem, 3) = "Win" Then
   SaveFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(CurFile, _
   "Text Delimited (*.txt), *.txt", , "Text Delimited Exporter")
Else
    SaveFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(CurFile, _
   "TEXT", , "Text Delimited Exporter")
End If

   ' Verifica se pressionou cancelar
   If SaveFileName = False Then
      WriteFile = "Canceled"
      Exit Function
   End If

  ' Inicia processo de escrita no arquivo
   FNum = FreeFile()

  Open SaveFileName For Output As #FNum

  ' Seleciona na planilha ativa as células utilizada 
  ActiveSheet.usedrange.select

  ' Busca o total de linhas e colunas selecionadas
  TotalRows = Selection.Rows.Count
  TotalCols = Selection.Columns.Count

  ' Inicia Loop para salvar cada célula no arquivo
  For RowNum = 1 To TotalRows
      For ColNum = 1 To TotalCols
         With Selection.Cells(RowNum, ColNum)
         Dim ColWidth as Integer
         ColWidth=Application.RoundUp(.ColumnWidth, 0)
         ' Grava o conteúdo da célula na variável
         Select Case .HorizontalAlignment
            Case xlRight
               CellText = Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text))) & .Text
            Case xlCenter
               CellText = Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text))/2) & .Text & _
                          Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text))/2)
            Case Else
               CellText = .Text & Space(Abs(ColWidth - Len(.Text)))
         End Select
         End With

         ' Grava o arquvio
         Select Case quotes
            Case vbYes
               CellText = Chr(34) & CellText & Chr(34) & delimiter
            Case vbNo
               CellText = CellText & delimiter
         End Select
         Print #FNum, CellText;

         ' Atualiza a barra de status conforme progresso
         Application.StatusBar = Format((((RowNum - 1) * TotalCols) _
            + ColNum) / (TotalRows * TotalCols), "0%") & " Completed."

      ' Próxima coluna no Loop
      Next ColNum

      ' Adiciona quebra de linha no final de cada linha
      If RowNum <> TotalRows Then Print #FNum, ""

   ' Proxima linha no Loop
   Next RowNum

   ' Fecha o arquivo
   Close #FNum

   ' Reseta a barra de status
   Application.StatusBar = False
   WriteFile = "Exported"
End Function
```

Fonte: https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/249885/formatted-text-.prn-is-limited-to-240-characters-per-line-in-excel

Comment: Perfeito Evert! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @DiegoSantos jóia! Quie bom que funcionou!! Não esqueça de marcar como resposta. Abs e boa sorte!!